# BackBlaze (B2) backup software recommendation

Tags: windows, backup

I am looking for software that I can use on Windows Servers for file backup tasks to BackBlaze (B2) cloud.

So far I have tried Duplicati, which runs OK on small(ish) data sets, but on larger I have issues where it never completes.

I am also testing CloudBerry (MSP360), and while it seems it will work, I see all sorts of bugs and it is also subscription based software. I would prefer something I can buy, set and forget.

Any recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We use Veeam agent + StarWind VTL offloading VBR archives to B2. Works flawlessly.

https://www.backblaze.com/blog/hybrid-cloud-example-veem-vtl-cloud/